# Laravel use join to fetch data return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

in this below result of fetch data:

```
{
    "purchases": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "member_id": 1,
            "mediator_id": 2,
            "type": null,
            "cash": 38712402,
            "created_at": "2017-11-08 06:40:45",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-08 06:40:45",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "cheques": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "purchase_id": 1,
                    "expire_date": "1396-01-19",
                    "amount": 97094060,
                    "isRejected": 0,
                    "created_at": "2017-11-08 06:40:45",
                    "updated_at": "2017-11-08 06:40:45",
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "member_id": 1,
            "mediator_id": 2,
            "type": null,
            "cash": 46760191,
            "created_at": "2017-11-08 06:40:45",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-08 06:40:45",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "cheques": []
        }
    ]
}
```

which i get that by this code:

```
$purchases = \App\Purchase::with('cheques')->where('member_id',
        $request->userId)->get();
```

i'm trying to get `amount` from `cheques` and `'cash','created_at'` from `purchases` where `'member_id'=$request->userId`, but i get empty `cheques` when i use this code:

```
$purchases = \App\Purchase::with(array('cheques'=>function($query){
        $query->select('amount');
    }))->where('member_id',$request->userId)->get(['cash','created_at']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$purchases = \App\Purchase::with(array('cheques'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'amount', 'purchase_id');
}))->where('member_id',$request->userId)->get(['cash','created_at']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Eager Loading Specific Columns` part from the documentation- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

It says:

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$purchases = \App\Purchase::with(
    array('cheques' => function($query){
        $query->select('amount');
    })
    )->where('member_id',$request->userId)
    ->select('cash','created_at')->get();
```

If you want to select columns using get methon of collection, you need to pass id:

`->get(['id', 'cash', 'created_at']);` or you can use `->select('cash', 'created_at')->get();`

Which you prefer.

Comment: `cheques` is null again

Comment: Can you try `$purchases = \App\Purchase::where('member_id',$request->userId)->with(array('cheques' => function($query){$query->select('amount');})->select('cash','created_at')->get();`